# "[object Object]" passed instead of the actual object as parameter

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, http, heroku

I am using Heroku with a Ruby on Rails application, and running from Safari.  I have the following Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : '/test_page',
    data : {stuff: arr1},
    dataType : 'script'
});
```

`arr1` is supposed to be an array of objects.  There's a `console.log` right before that, and it is:

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, ...]
```

However, I got an error on the server side when I made this ajax call.  The logs showed

```
2012-10-01T03:13:34+00:00 app[web.1]: Parameters: {"stuff"=>"[object Object]"}
2012-10-01T03:13:34+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
2012-10-01T03:13:34+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `to_hash' for "[object Object]":String):
2012-10-01T03:13:34+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms
```

I'm unable to replicate the error - every time I've tried it since, it has worked perfectly, and it was always working perfectly before (in that sense, anyway).  The call was even the exact same call that I've made dozens of times, since it's one of my test cases, so it's not anything to do with changing the data that was sent.  It's really confusing to me - what would cause that string to sometimes be passed to the server instead of the object?

I think it may be related to the "Can't verify CSRF token authenticity" line, because that doesn't show in the logs for the other, successful requests.

For those wondering about the `dataType: 'script'`, it is there because the response is a rendered js.erb file - see http://lathamcity.com/posts/ajaxInRails.html

Comment: If you send "arr1" as the *value* of a parameter, you're going to get that. Basically your setup is broken. Send the objects as discrete parameters.

Comment: A js.erb file is rendered on the server-side and run as a response.  That has been there for hundreds of server calls.

Comment: Pointy, what do you mean?  I'm sending `arr1`, not `"arr1"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
dataType : 'script'
```

Are you sure this will work..

Try

```
dataType : 'json'
```

Also make sure you use json.stringify on the data you send

```
data : {"stuff" : JSON.stringify(arr1)},
```

Make sure your key is enclosed in Quotes

Comment: This will work.  The call has only failed that one time, all the other times it is successful.  `dataType : 'script'` is because I am rendering a js.erb file in response - see http://lathamcity.com/posts/ajaxInRails.html

Comment: The calls have been working consistently except for this one time.  If it were a problem related to anything you've described in this answer, wouldn't they either always work or never work?